# Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v8.17.0. Update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

when i run the project with rails, it give me error: Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v8.17.0. Update it.

i read on others with have same problem, they can fixed it with using

> gem 'mini_racer'

but i tried to do the same, and it give me another error when i tried to bundle install, it says ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. what should i do?

> Installing libv8-node 16.10.0.0 (x86_64-linux-musl) Fetching
> mini_racer 0.5.0 Installing mini_racer 0.5.0 with native extensions
> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mini_racer-0.5.0/ext/mini_racer_extension
> ```
>
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/bin/ruby -I
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
> ./siteconf20211130-22506-1ik7po.rb extconf.rb checking for
> -lpthread... yes creating Makefile
>
> current directory:
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mini_racer-0.5.0/ext/mini_racer_extension
> make "DESTDIR=" clean
>
> current directory:
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mini_racer-0.5.0/ext/mini_racer_extension
> make "DESTDIR=" compiling mini_racer_extension.cc cc1plus: warning:
> command line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for
> C++ cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option
> ‘-Wno-tautological-compare’ cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command
> line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command
> line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ cc1plus: warning: unrecognized
> command line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ cc1plus: warning:
> unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-cast-function-type’ linking
> shared-object mini_racer_extension.so g++: error:
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/x86_64-linux/libv8/obj/libv8_monolith.a: No such file or directory Makefile:260: recipe for target
> 'mini_racer_extension.so' failed make: *** [mini_racer_extension.so]
> Error 1
>
> make failed, exit code 2
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/mini_racer-0.5.0 for inspection.
> Results logged to
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.6.0/mini_racer-0.5.0/gem_make.out
>
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:99:in
> `run'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in` block in make'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in
> `each'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in` make'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:62:in `block in build'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:295:in` open'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:29:in `build'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:185:in` block in build_extension'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:235:in
> `mon_synchronize'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:181:in` build_extension'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:229:in
> `block in build_extensions'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:226:in` each'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:226:in
> `build_extensions'   /home/jafar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/installer.rb:830:in` build_extensions'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:71:in `build_extensions'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/rubygems_gem_installer.rb:28:in` install'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:200:in
> `install'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:54:in` install'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/installer/gem_installer.rb:16:in `install_from_spec'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:186:in` do_install'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/installer/parallel_installer.rb:177:in
> `block in worker_pool'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/worker.rb:62:in` apply_func'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/worker.rb:57:in
> `block in process_queue'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in` loop'
> /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/worker.rb:54:in
> `process_queue'   /home/jafar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/gems/bundler-2.2.32/lib/bundler/worker.rb:91:in` block (2 levels) in create_threads'
>
> An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.5.0), and Bundler
> cannot continue.
>
> In Gemfile:   mini_racer

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu OS? Please let me know the version of Ubuntu OS you have.

Comment: yes, i'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Try this into Gemfile. `gem 'mini_racer', '0.2.1'` .